# In Stock/Out of Stock - can I add a blank so there is no availbitly response?

Tags: inventory

can I add a blank so availability has no answer next to it?
https://www.modwalls.com/real-penny-mosaics-mix.html

I need this for our preorder plug in :) -

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your question. You want to add a blank stock availability message?

Answer (score 0):

Two cases, let's check each one:

## 1. Good theme, maybe even standard one:

1. Go to Administrator section:
2. *Configuration > General*
3. *Catalog > Inventory* (From left sidebar)
4. Search for option:

*Display products availability in stock in the frontend*
and set it to **No**

5. Clear Your cache.

If it doesn't work proceed with next step.

## 2. Custom theme, probably not following some standards

The template file responsible for rendering Availability's HTML code is placed in path:
`magento_pub/app/design/frontend/your_theme/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/CORRESPONDING_PRODUCT_TYPE.phtml`

so if in your case product's only simple - default product then it will be file:
`magento_pub/app/design/frontend/your_theme/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml`

or if it will be configurable product it will reside in:
`magento_pub/app/design/frontend/your_theme/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/configurable.phtml`

The rest of files are deprecated from previous Magento version so they should be blank - check it just to be sure.

Open the file that's corresponding to your product types and search for:

```
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
    <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Normally it would be wrapped in `if` statement, so do it this way:

```
<?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
    <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now the option from Administrator panel should do it's work.

Edit:
I've just re-read your question, do you mean the:

a. Availability: In stock

or

b. Need more than we have in stock? Contact us!

Let me know in comments and I'll update my answer.